# Factories with different amount of products and chance of being broken delivered to a store

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Three factories deliver the same product to a store. The chances of broken products per factory are:

1. First factory: $3$%
2. Second factory: $2$%
3. Third factory: $1$%

Knowing that the second factory delivers two times more products than the first and two times less than the third what is the probability of selecting a broken product at random from the store?

I tried $1\times\frac{3}{100} + 2\times\frac{2}{100} + 4\times\frac{1}{100}$.

Comment: And your answer can't be right: suppose that the FIRST factory produced only broken items. By your reasoning there would be a greater than a 100% chance of getting a broken product...

Comment: @PavanC I voted to reject your edit because it changed the intent of the original post: you replaced the '2 X2 /100' with 2/100...

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition is sound, re the relative chances of a product coming
from each store, but you must first **normalize** the probabilities of the product coming from each store.

The chances that a product comes from F-1 (factory 1) is $(1/7).$

The chances that a product comes from F-2 is $(2/7).$

The chances that a product comes from F-3 is $(4/7).$

So, the correct computation is

$$[(1/7) \times (0.03)] + [(2/7) \times (0.02)] + [(4/7) \times (0.01)].$$

Comment: Can you explain why 7 for the denominator?

Comment: @Adam_alex Normalizing the relative chances that a product comes from each factory means that the sum of these *normalized* probabilities must equal $(1)$.  The relative chances are in the proportion of $(1)$ to $(2)$ to $(4)$.  Further, $1 + 2 + 4 = 7.$  So I normalized the probabilities by dividing each of the relative chances $\{1,2,4\}$ by $(7)$.

Comment: @Adam_alex another way of seeing this answer is: suppose Factory 1 produces 100 items, Factory 2 produces 200, and Factory 3 produces 400. The total number produced is 700. The expected numbers of bad products from Factories 1, 2, and 3  are respectively $3 = 100 \times .03$, $4= 200 \times .02$ and  $4 = 400 \times .01$. So the probability of getting a bad product is $ ( 3 + 4  +  4 ) / 700 = 11/ 700$. This is pretty much the same as the normalization - i.e., by distributing the $1/700$. Hope this helps...

Comment: Thank you all for your time.

Comment: @Adam_alex if user2661923's answer helped you, 'accept' it...